# Googlesheets R Error: inherits(ss, "googlesheet") is not TRUE

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I am attempting to automatically update a Google Sheets with R. When I run the `gs_edit_cells()` command I get the error:

```
Error: inherits(ss, "googlesheet") is not TRUE
```

I am not really understanding the error, or at least I might be misunderstanding it. The code I am running is:

```
gs_edit_cells(ss = 'Stats', ws = 1, input = mydf, anchor = "A1", byrow = FALSE,
          col_names = FALSE, trim = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```

where `mydf` is a dataframe (of reasonable dimensions), and `'Stats'` is the name of the Google Sheet. I have attempted with all other identifying fields retrieved from the `gs_ls()` command, e.g. `sheet_key` , `ws_feed`, URL, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6):

I expand my comment, with many of the `googlesheets::` functions, you are supposed to provide a `ss` argument which is defined as:

> ss    :   a registered Google spreadsheet, i.e. a **googlesheet** object

So `ss` cannot be a string like *'stats'*, it must be an object of class `googlesheet`, typically created with the `gs_title` function. Try this:

```
mysheet <- gs_title("Stats")
gs_edit_cells(ss = mysheet, ws = 1, input = mydf, anchor = "A1", byrow = FALSE,
              col_names = FALSE, trim = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```